# Ruby Bundler Version Dependency Confusion in Lockfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, gemfile

I will try and keep this focused.

When trying to move from a **working** bundler 1.14.6 combined with a **Gemfile** + **Gemfile.lock** to 1.15.2 or higher I ran into some failures in our old project's install. We believe that the failure is caused from a **Gemfile.lock** that is specified in a way that stricter parsing in 1.15.x and higher doesn't like. (found a vague reference to this in an issue posted somewhere on github, lost the reference.  Manual resolution was recommended)

On the road to trying to fix it I am faced with trying to understand WHY it is failing and WHAT this has to do with it.

The error I am currently working on is shown below:

```
Downloading twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.0 revealed dependencies not in the API
or the lockfile (therubyracer (~> 0.10.1), less-rails (~> 2.2.2)).
```

Focussing on the less-rails problem, when I do a

```
gem list
```

I get the indication that less-rails is already at 2.2.4.

```
less-rails (2.2.4)
```

Why isn't the specified **less-rails (~> 2.2.2)** not happy with the **2.2.4** that is installed?

Please help me understand so I can take a run at fixing the other issues popping up.

Here is the gemfile and gemfile.lock that exhibits the problem.

Really struggling to understand this one, any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Try `gem uninstall less-rails`. Then run `bundle install` again.

Comment: I will try.  I do start from scratch each time. I'll report back if anything is found!